# How to handle 1000's of static pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Part of my rails app will comprise a very large number of static pages all with the same layout (potentially thousands). Whats the best structure for dealing with this - store them in a database? And is there a way to quickly generate all these pages rather than add them one at a time...www.root.com/city1/local_town1, www.root.com/city1/local_town2 etc

Comment: If they all use the same layout, why not just make it a proper view and let rails do the heavy lifting as needed?  That is, if you have two of the "same" static page, you don't have a static page anymore.

Comment: Maybe he's importing a legacy static webpage into rails? Ha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data**

Firstly, you'll be much better suited to not calling them "pages" - Rails has the potential to serve millions of records if you want it to.

You need to switch your paradigm to thinking of them as pieces of data / content which you can store in a database. This is the magic of Rails - the ability to serve data from a db, which you can then mould to your application's styling etc.

To get a good idea about this, you should read up on [how to write a blog app in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application)

--

You'll want to set something up like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, path: "", only: [:show, :index]

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @pages = Page.all
   end

   def show
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    #fields id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/views/pages/index.html.erb
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
   <%= link_to @page.title, page %>
<% end %>

#app/views/pages/show.html.erb
<%= @page.title %>
<%= @page.body %>
```

--

This will give you the ability to populate your `Page` model with the "pages" you have. Notice the difference here - you're not actually writing each "page" individually (in HTML) - you're populating *data* which can then be shown in any way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer Rich. I'm also going to have an app running on the domain - someone else recommended the best way to do this would be to generate static pages that live outside my rails app, and are served from nginx, or Apache? What does this actually mean technically!?

Comment: When you mention you're going to "have an app running on the domain", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I need a large static customer facing site in addition to an app that will be used by customers/staff/management to do things like schedule jobs/add customer records/accept customer payments etc

Comment: Why don't you just keep it all in one Rails app, and have "staff" area as an admin area? I can give you an update on how to achieve that if you need

Comment: I guess I could but from the research I've done theres been some suggestion that it might be better to serve these pages via a CDN in order to reduce requests...from a codeship.io blog post: "As the Heroku Cedar stack has no Proxy in front of your Rails application any more static assets have to be delivered through your application. This is very inefficient and keeps your dynos or unicorn workers busy with serving your assets...This shows how we use the Asset Pipeline, Compass and Amazon Cloudfront to serve all of our assets fast without sending any requests to our application directly."

Comment: Sure - you can use a CDN for any superfluous calls you need. However, you're asking about using "1,000's of static pages" -- I recommended keeping them in your Rails app. What I recommended was essentially what Wordpress does, except with more scope for extensibility

Comment: Ah right so basically set up a blog as per your link?

Comment: To begin with, yes. At least you'll get your data into your database. Then you can extrapolate as you wish

Comment: No problem - hope it helps!